# How to add the values I've passed into my method? Java

Tags: java, methods

**Question** How can I use the values that I have passed to my addValues method to return the total

There is a bit of code that determines the prices, however to narrow exactly what I am trying to pinpoint down I have "hard coded" the values into this example.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
price = 100;
price1 = 5000;
price2 = 2000;
price3 = 20000;
price4 = 500;
price5 = 50;

ThisIsGarage values = new ThisIsGarage();
    garage.addValues(price);
    garage.addValues(price1);
    garage.addValues(price2);
    garage.addValues(price3);
    garage.addValues(price4);
    garage.addValues(price5);
}
```

It passes the prices to my addValues method

```
public class ThisIsGarage
{
 public int addValues(int vals)
  {
   int values = vals;
   System.out.println(values);
   return values;
  }
}
```

My program is currently printing out the values correctly, I am just not sure how to add them together,

Comment: Theory is what makes it easier to decide on how to solve your problems

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for your response. I am not discrediting the theory of it I am simply stating that I can evaluate more easily on code than theory.

Comment: The problem is, most people talk in "theory"; "Use pattern X", for example, understanding these theories will not only make it easier to understand what people are talking about, but also allow you to see how best to solve problems in the future, I don't know about other people, but I tend to think of how one or more patterns might be used to solve the problems I face in my day to day work. Very few solutions are presented in such away that they resolve all the problems you are having, so you need to be able to see the pattern been presented and modify it to your needs ;)

Comment: you're very right. it's been a long day for me and i have spent many of hours working on this program. I appreciate your help and I apologize for my current lack of motivation.

Comment: Just beware, most people take offense and people asking "just for code", at least you provided some example of your effort ;)

Comment: I will take note, and thank you once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Builder style pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html), for example

```
public class ThisIsGarage {

    private int total = 0;

    public ThisIsGarage addValues(int vals) {
        total += vals;
        return this;
    }

    public int tally() {
        return total;
    }
}
```

Which you could use something like...

```
int price = 100;
int price1 = 5000;
int price2 = 2000;
int price3 = 20000;
int price4 = 500;
int price5 = 50;

ThisIsGarage garage = new ThisIsGarage();
int tally = garage.addValues(price).
        addValues(price1).
        addValues(price2).
        addValues(price3).
        addValues(price4).
        addValues(price5)
        .tally();
System.out.println(tally);
```

Or you could just keep track of the tally as you add values it the object

```
public class ThisIsGarage {

    private int total = 0;

    public int addValues(int vals) {
        total += vals;
        return total;
    }
}
```

which could be used something like this...

```
int price = 100;
int price1 = 5000;
int price2 = 2000;
int price3 = 20000;
int price4 = 500;
int price5 = 50;

ThisIsGarage garage = new ThisIsGarage();
garage.addValues(price);
garage.addValues(price1);
garage.addValues(price2);
garage.addValues(price3);
garage.addValues(price4);
int tally = garage.addValues(price5);
System.out.println(tally);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, MadProgrammer.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you :

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int price = 100;
    int price1 = 5000;
    int price2 = 2000;
    int price3 = 20000;
    int price4 = 500;
    int price5 = 50;

    ThisIsGarage values = new ThisIsGarage();
    values.addValues(price);
    values.addValues(price1);
    values.addValues(price2);
    values.addValues(price3);
    values.addValues(price4);
    values.addValues(price5);
    values.printResult();
    }


public class ThisIsGarage {

    int temp = 0;

    public int addValues(int vals)
      {
       int values = vals;
       temp = temp + vals;
       System.out.println(values);
       return values;
      }
    public void printResult(){
        System.out.println("Addition >>>>>>>>>"+temp);
    }
```